# How can I "collapse" nested `if let` statements which all run the same code in their `else` clauses?

Tags: rust

Here's a simple example:

```rust
if let Some(x) = y {
    if let Some(t) = u {
        do_thing = false;
    } else {
        do_thing = true;
    }
} else {
    do_thing = true;
}
```

I would think that you could just have something like...

```rust
if let Some(x) = y && let Some(t) = u {
    do_thing = false;
} else {
    do_thing = true;
}
```

...but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a clean solution to this?

Comment: They are working on it, I think it’s available on nightly with the feature flag `if_let_chains`, but I’m not sure, so you might have to check it yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
if let (Some(x), Some(t)) = (y, u) {
    do_thing = false;
} else {
    do_thing = true;
}
```

if you don't need values then you can write

```rust
if y.is_some() && u.is_some() { ... }
```

Comment: even better: `let do_thing = if let (Some(x), Some(t)) = (y, u) {
    false
} else {
    true
};`

Comment: worth mentioning that the first option *won't* provide short-circuiting, but OP might not care about that